Efficient vectorisation of cpp functions with if/else logic
Say, I have a C++ function:
int arr_1[1000];
double arr_2[1000];

// arr_1 and arr_2 to be assigned values. 
// This step is neglected. Not important.

double val(int i){
    
    int a = arr_1[i];
    int b = arr_1[i+1];
    
    if (a == b) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else {
        // arr_1 is properly designed so not to worry about any kind of leakage.
        return arr_2[a] * arr_2[b];
    }
}

For example, I call this function 100 times.
int main() {
    double result = 0.0;

    for (int k=0; k<100; ++k) {
        result += val(k);
    }
return 0;
}

Is there an efficient way to vectorize this function under the SIMD (Single instruction, multiple data)? I work on Apple M1 chip so the right library is #include <arm_neon.h>.
Auto-vectorisation is not done by the complier under -o3 flag due to that if/else logic and also the array slicing in arr_2.
I could not think of a way that could completely avoid the for loop. Since I have a if/else logic so I always need a for loop to do comparison use vcgtq_f32 from arm_neon.h. That then boils everything down to not doing any kind of vectorisation.
The actual running time may just be a few hundred nanoseconds. But I am wondering how to reduce the timing for this simple example since there are lots of other real-world examples could be optimised similarly based on the vectorization of this toy code.

There is no loop in this code. There is nothing to vectorize.

@JaMiT, sorry a typo, arr_2.

@j6t, I add an example for loop to call this function.

That loop doesn't make any sense. Please write a proper minimal, reproducible example. While you are at it, you can edit your tags and remove AVX since, as you remarked yourself, you cannot use that since you use an entirely different CPU architecture

What is i in your loop? Did you mean k?

Looking past the minor issues here, it is possible to make a vectorized version of val with some specific SIMD ISA extensions (there is no "the SIMD framework"), but since you have an arbitrary indirection it would require some form of "gather", and that doesn't tend to be very efficient. NEON doesn't have any "gather" operation. SVE does.

@Siguza, yes. Typo fixed.

The if/else logic isn't a big deal in SVE, which supports masking. In NEON, well you can't "gather" in NEON so this whole thing breaks down anyway, but in other situations you can blend two different results depending on a condition and such (with some opportunity for simplification, such as if one of the results is zero which is the case here)

@user555045, could you please write a code to vectorize it using SVE?

@TonyShi no thanks, but if you give it a try and fail you can post another question about that and maybe someone can fix it

First off, you want to reduce the branches or calls.  For example, tag your function as "inline" or just move the code to the main() function.  Function calls wreak havoc with vectorization.  Secondly, try unrolling the loop to see if there is a way to vectorize the code or run it in parallel.

I'm wondering if SIMD isn't a solution in search of a problem here: there might be other ways to optmize your algorithm. Your program computes a sum a*b + b*c + c*d + d*e + ... (with some terms conditionally disabled). By computing b*(a+c) + d*(c+e) + ... (with some terms conditionally disabled) instead, you will get almost the same result, while doing 50% less multiplications. It's worth a benchmark on your side.

@user555045, I checked that Apple M1 chip does not support SVE, arm_sve.h. Are you ware of other SIMD extensions that could support gathering other than AVX2, AVX512 since I don't have Intel CPUs at the moment.

gather loads are generally poorly supported on CPUs at the moment. Even if the instruction exists, it may be slow. If you switch the datatype to float, a GPU (even a built-in) would be able to handle this fine since gather loads with decent locality of data are essentially the same as texture lookups. But customer-level GPUs cannot handle double arithmetic with reasonable performance, if at all.

@Homer512, certainly I can use float if the computational accuracy is not that high. But is there a way to reduce the overhead for using CUDA? For example, opening a GPU outside the function so the overhead is only counted once for multiple function calls.

Well, yeah, of course you would lift the initialization out of the function and reuse as much as possible, maybe move more computations onto the GPU to limit the memory transfer costs etc. But does the M1 even use CUDA? I thought those use Apple's Metal API. And of course the whole endeavour require sufficient data size and cost of computation to make outsourcing even worthwhile.

The M1 does not support CUDA because it does not have an Nvidia GPU (unofficial solution are AFAIK far from being sufficiently advanced to be used in production). The M1 does not support SVE either. Gather instruction are indeed generally slow, but better than doing manual scalar loads on quite-recent Intel x86 CPUs (still slow on AMD ZenX). Using Metal only worth it if the array is shared with the GPU (which is possible), however, the loop is so small that running a kernel on the GPU should be slower than doing the actual operation on CPU... Same for spawning multiple threads.

If a == b if very often true, then you can write an SIMD code optimistically assuming that and fallback if this is not true (significantly slower in this case). However, I do not think it worth it on the M1 because Neon can only hold 2 double per register. It might be a good idea with float though. One might also be able to improve a bit the scalar code by increasing the ILP and reducing the memory latency overhead though the benefit will certainly not be huge. I do not think there is anything else better to do on the M1.

@JérômeRichard, I am now not obliged to M1 chips. So, SVE and CUDA are back up. Since SVE can gather much more elements than neon or AVX at one time, is now SVE the best solution for that? a==b is not quite often true so optimising from this point does not quite work.

@TonyShi AFAIK, only few ARM CPUs support SVE currently. The only ones I know are HPC/datacenter CPUs : the A64FX of the Japanese supercomputer and the ARM Neoverse V1/V2/V3 CPUs (used by recent Amazon Graviton CPUs). AFAIK SVE is not guaranteed to be wider than AVX/AVX-512 in practice. In fact, it is not the case so far on all ARM CPU implementations. SVE support variable vector size. A typical implementation use 256-bit hardware units/registers (possibly 512 bit but not more). It can do that by fusing SIMD units. Put it shortly, SVE is certainly not much better than AVX/AVX-512 for that.

We have far too little information on your actual use case to advise on the use of GPUs. This operation, as it is presented with 1000 samples is certainly too small. 10e3 samples at once, that could work. And of course everything depends on how much and how often data has to be transferred. Even with an onboard GPU you have to consider which cache the data would reside in. In any case, you have to take the entire program and system into account.
